# Why onclick function isn't rendering (React.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I’m working on building an e-commerce website in React. In which, there will be a navigation bar with all the categories and once a user clicked on a specific category, it will render all the products that belongs to the checked category in the same page. In the project I have two `.js` files which are `NavBar.js` where it contains all the stuff for the navigation bar and `AllItems.js` where all products are rendered.

My problem now, is that `onclick` in `NavBar.js` doesn't render `AllItems.js`. It works with `console.log("sss")` but it doesn't work with `<AllItems/>`

Here is my code in `NavBar.js`

```
function NavBar() {


    const [allCategories, setAllCategories] = useState([])
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState([])
    

    useEffect(() => {

        fetchAnyQuery(
            `
            query{
                categories{
                name
                }
            }
        `).then(data => {
            setAllCategories( data.data.categories )
        })
    },[])

    // for currency options
    useEffect(() => {

        fetchAnyQuery(`
            query{
              currencies
            }
        `
        ).then(data => {
            setCurrency(data.data.currencies)
        })
    },[])


    return (
        <nav id = "NavBar">
            <div id="NavBar-content">

                <div className = "leftSide" id = "leftNav">

                    {allCategories.map((allCategories, index) => {

                        if (index == 0){
                            // return a checked tab

                            return(
                                <>
                                    <input className='radio-category' id={allCategories.name} type='radio' name="nav" onClick={
                                        function (){
                                            console.log("ssss");
                                            <AllItems/>

                                        }

                                    } checked/>
                                    <label htmlFor={allCategories.name} className='category-label'><h5 className="tab-text">{allCategories.name.toUpperCase()}</h5></label>
                                </>
                            )

                        }
                        else {
                            // return unchecked tab

                            return(
                                <>
                                    <input className='radio-category' id={allCategories.name} type='radio' name="nav" onClick={ function (){changeCategoryState(allCategories.name); <AllItems/>} } />
                                    <label htmlFor={allCategories.name} className='category-label'><h5 className="tab-text">{allCategories.name.toUpperCase()}</h5></label>
                                </>
                            )
                        }

                    })}
                </div>

                <div className = "centerSide">
                    {/*<a href="/">*/}
                    {/*    /!*<img src={logo} />*!/*/}
                    {/*    Logo*/}
                    {/*</a>*/}

                    <button onClick={function (){ console.log(getCategoryState()) }}>
                        Abo Kalb
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div className = "rightSide">

                    <select className="currencySelector" id="currencySelector">

                        {currency.map((currency, index) =>{

                            return(
                                <option value={ JSON.stringify(currency.indexOf(index)) }  >   {getSymbolFromCurrency(currency.toString()) + " " + currency.toString()} </option>

                            )
                        })}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Also, here is my code for `AllItems.js` file:

```
function AllItems() {

    // The state that I want to use in NavBar.js
    // const [category, setCategory] = useState([getCategoryState()])
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])



    useEffect(() => {

        fetchAnyQuery(
            `
                query{
                    categories{
                        name
                        products{
                            name
                            id
                        }
                    }
                }
        `
        ).then(data => {

            // Here I'm trying to do all  the required stuff

           // console.log(category)

        })


    },[])


    console.log("All Items RENDERED!!")

    return (
        <>

            <h1>{ getCategoryState() }</h1>

            <div className="itemContainer" id="itemContainer">

            </div>

        </>

    )
}

export default AllItems;
```

Comment: You should probably have a parent component that handles the state of the clicked radio button, and that renders the items based on that state.

Comment: @Andy I just edited the question. There was some misunderstanding with it. Feel free to read it again

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to render different categories' data based on which category is clicked, but you can not call a component on the click, that's not how React works. Instead set a state and render the component conditionally according to the state value, and set the state when the component needs to be rendered.

Assuming that you're fetching your items from a server, you will have to store that data in a state

```
const [allItems, setAllTems] = useState([])
```

Then add a state that will help you render your items conditionally

```
const [showAllItems, setShowAllItems] = useState(false)
```

In your JSX, use && to render your data when the state gets all the data

```
<> {showAllItems && <AllItems>} </>
```

if you're having troubles understanding how this works, I suggest you checking [React documentations](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), it explains very well how you can manipulate the state

Comment: Items page details is implemented in AllItems.js and `Navbar.js` is just the implementation of the navigation bar it's not possible to put `<>{showAllItems ? <AllItems /> : null}</>` in `NavBar.js`. That will display every thing inside the navigation bar

Comment: I just edited the question. There was some misunderstanding with it. Feel free to read it again

Comment: In this case, you can either use a parent component to manage both components states or the context hook provided by react

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent component to manage the state. When you update the radio input in `Nav` update the state, and then filter the data based on that selection.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  const [ items, setItems ] = useState(data);
  const [ selection, setSelection ] = useState('');

  // When you click a button, set the selection state
  function handleClick(e) {
    setSelection(e.target.dataset.type); 
  }

  // `filter` out the items you want to display
  // based on the selection
  function filteredItems() {
    return items.filter(item => item.type === selection);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav>
        Dairy: <input onClick={handleClick} type="radio" data-type="dairy" name="food" />
        Meat: <input onClick={handleClick} type="radio" data-type="meat" name="food" />
        Vegetable: <input onClick={handleClick} type="radio" data-type="vegetable" name="food" />
      </Nav>
      <Items items={filteredItems()} />
    </div>
  );
};

// `map` over the filtered data
function Items({ items }) {
  return items.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>);
}

function Nav({ children }) {
  return children;
}

const data = [
  { name: 'cow', type: 'meat' },
  { name: 'bree', type: 'dairy' },
  { name: 'chicken', type: 'meat' },
  { name: 'sprout', type: 'vegetable' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```